# have some issue when I try to conver php code to javascript with simple operator

Tags: javascript, php

php

```
($array->name& "apple") == "apple"&& $array->fruit
```

=> this is php code

and I would like to change this code to javascript , but for me it is bit hard to understand the code
this part

```
($array->name& "apple") == "apple"
```

and I try to change this code to javascript like this

js

```
if(array.name){
array.name==="apple" && array.fruit ? return true : false
}
```

but I'm not sure this code correct or not. and I don't know what is the exact meaing of

```
($array->name& "apple") == "apple"
```

so what is difference between  ($array->name& "apple") == "apple" and array.name ==="apple" ??

Comment: That bit of PHP code does indeed make little sense. Simple testing can show that `($array->name & "apple") == "apple"` is equivalent to `$array->name == "apple"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending from who/where comes from this code, but a simple "&" is a mask function.

It's is useful in case you want to mask a first var by a second like so :

```
"11001010" & "11110000"  // Will return 11000000
```

I can't explain you in some lines, so you can google it

But i guess this make no sense on alphabet, so your code is probably invalid.